# PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: oracle, procedure, nested-table, object-type, bulk-collect

Im creating a procedure to display the n number of maximum and minimum salary for an employee. If i ll give 5 as input, the query will get me 5 maximum and minimum salary for an employee.

For the above scenario, I have created an object with two columns like below

```
create type vrec as object(
empno number,
sal number
);
/
```

Then i created nested table with the help of object type, so that i can use the nested table as out parameter to return all the rows at one short.

```
create type vrec_type is table of vrec;
/
```

After the data type creation, im creating a procedure like below

```
create or replace procedure pro_first_last(input in number,salary out vrec_type)
is
begin
select empno,sal BULK COLLECT INTO salary from (
select empno,sal from  
(select empno,sal,rank() over(order by sal asc) min_sal from emp5 where sal is not null) where min_sal <= 5
union all
select empno,sal from 
(select empno,sal,rank() over(order by sal desc) max_sal from emp5 where sal is not null) where max_sal <= 5);
for i in salary.first..salary.last
loop
dbms_output.put_line(salary(i).empno);
end loop;
end;
/
```

When i compiling the above procedure, im getting not enough values. I have also created the object with two columns and in select statement also im returning only two column. Could someone review and help me on this or provide some alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly adding `empno, sal` values into `salary` (`vrec_type` object, which can take the values of only object type `vrec`)

You need to create the `object` of `vrec` and then add it into `salary` as following:

```
create or replace procedure pro_first_last(input in number,salary out vrec_type)
is
begin
  select vrec(empno,sal) -- change in this line
         BULK COLLECT INTO salary from ( 
    select empno,sal from  
      (select empno,sal,rank() over(order by sal asc) min_sal from emp5 where sal is not null) where min_sal <= 5
    union all
    select empno,sal from 
     (select empno,sal,rank() over(order by sal desc) max_sal from emp5 where sal is not null) where max_sal <= 5);
    for i in salary.first..salary.last
      loop
        dbms_output.put_line(salary(i).empno);
    end loop;
end;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Tejash Awesome!!!! Much thanks for your help. Are we able to create this procedure without using bulk collect. I facing an issues without using bulk collect. Could you able to help me with that too.

Comment: Please create a new question to avoid the mess!! :)

Comment: Tejash i have added a new code by creating the procedure and it got compiled successfully. But when i ran the block to see the output i got error like 'Reference to uninitialized collections'

Comment: You should initialize salary to empty collection in procedure as the error will be thrown if there is no data found by query.